# Chrome html-video invisible start playing until I scroll the page

Tags: html, html5-video

I have built a site trying to play a video as a big background image.The element is invisible until i start scrolling. I have no javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<video class="background_video" poster="video/rain.jpg" autoplay muted="true" preload="auto" >
  <source type="video/mp4" src="video/rain.mp4">
  <source type="video/ogv" src="video/rain.ogv">
  <source type="video/webm" src="video/rain.webm">
</video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bug with chrome and use of the poster-attribute. Found the js in the reply on this one do the trick.

[video disappears when poster attribute and preload is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492198/video-disappears-when-poster-attribute-and-preload-is-defined/17216002#17216002)