# Vimeo/YouTube — Play video as you scroll into view

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, scroll, vimeo

I'm wondering if it's possible to play a video (preferably Vimeo) as you scroll into view. I have a single scrolling site and the video is an animation so it's key for it not to start until you scroll down to it.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks,
R

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340763/chrome-html-video-invisible-start-playing-until-i-scroll-the-page

Answer (score 1):

You could use a "[scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)" and then trigger play when the preferred position is viewed. Good luck!